# SQL Server : trigger firing every time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers, constraints

For my school project I need to add a trigger to my SQL Server database. I decided a 'no double usernames' trigger on my `Users` table would be relevant.

The problem is, that this trigger is firing every time I execute an `INSERT` query. I can't figure out why this is happening every time. I even tried different ways of writing my trigger.

The trigger I have now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger_NoDuplicates]
ON [dbo].[Users]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF(EXISTS(SELECT Username FROM Users 
              WHERE Username = (SELECT Username FROM inserted)))
    BEGIN;
        RAISERROR('This username already exists!',15, 0)
        ROLLBACK
    END
END
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could just add a unique index on the username instead of the whole trigger.

Comment: @juergend The trigger is a learning objective for this project, that's why I am adding this trigger

Comment: `begin;` - why the `;`? Remove it.

Comment: @juergend woops, removed it, makes no difference though. I tried a lot of different notations. Can't figure out why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trigger always fires every time, do you mean "raises an error every time"?

You currently have the following *(expanded to multiple lines to make it clearer*)...

```
IF (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT Username
      FROM users
     WHERE Username = (SELECT Username FROM inserted)
  )
)
```

The key point here is the name of the table `inserted`.  Past tense.  It's already happened.

Anything in the `inserted` table has ***already*** been inserted into the target table.

So, what you need to check is that the username is in the target table *more* than once already.

***However***, it is possible to insert more than one record in to a table at once.  This means that `Username = (SELECT Username FROM inserted)` will cause its own error.  *(You can't compare a single value to a set of values, and `inserted` can contain more than one row => more than one username...)*

This is how I would approach your trigger...

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT
    users.Username
  FROM
    users
  INNER JOIN
    inserted
      ON  inserted.Username = users.Username
  GROUP BY
    users.Username
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

This takes the *(already inserted in to)* users table, and picks out all the records that mach username with any record in the `inserted` table.

Then it `GROUP`s them by they `username` field.

Then it filters the results to *only* include groups with more than 1 record.

These groups *(usernames)*, have duplicate entries and should cause your trigger to raise an error.

An alternative is a bit more similar to your approach, but many people won't recognise it, so I generally wouldn't recommend it...

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT
    users.Username
  FROM
    users
  WHERE
    users.Username = ANY (SELECT username FROM inserted)
  GROUP BY
    users.Username
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

The `ANY` keyword gets very rarely used, but does what it sounds like.  It allows a single value to be compared to a set of values.

Finally, if your table has an `IDENTITY` column, you can avoid the `GROUP BY` by explicitly stating you don't want to compare a row to itself...

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT
    users.Username
  FROM
    users
  INNER JOIN
    inserted
      ON  inserted.Username  = users.Username
      AND inserted.id       <> users.id
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear and extensive explanation. It wasn't clear to me yet that when this trigger executes the username is already inserted. Sounds very logical afterwards. Thanks!